# How do I time JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, performance

My processor runs at 2.0 GHz.

I have a new computer with as much software removed as possible except my development tools.  This system is clean with no malware.

When I run the code below I get about 2M loops per second.  That is about 1 MHz.

Suppose doing and addition, and doing a compare takes 10x the simplest operation, I get about 10 MHz

Why do I not get more utilization of my processor?

```
var Utility = 
{
    time: function() 
    {
        var end_time,
            start_time,
            index = 0;

        start_time = new Date().getTime();

        while ( index <= 1000000 )
        {
            index++;
        }

        end_time = new Date().getTime();

    return ( end_time - start_time);
    }
};
```

Comment: why don't you just set a timeout?

Comment: In what world does `0.1 * 100` = `1`?

Comment: The calls to construct new Date objects will involve a system call into the operating system in order to get the current time.  That's going to be the lion's share of the work done.

Comment: Oh also if I found out your website was doing this to my browser I'd never visit it again and I'd tell my family and pets never to visit it either.

Comment: @Pointy and all others - I think he's just trying to measure the CPU speed with JavaScript code.

Comment: Also, a line of JavaScript code typically involves ***many*** CPU instructions.

Comment: @ShadowWizard that may be true but the name of the function ("pause") is mighty suspicious.  People ask about doing delay routines with tight loops all the time here.

Comment: I get 2,657,169 OPS at 3.4Ghz hehe (Using chrome)

Comment: I downvoted your question because you seem to fail to understand the difference between high-level code (like JavaScript) and the low-level instructions that a CPU executes. Because of the way you have worded the question, you come off as presumptuous and arrogant, expecting that the problem is surely not with you. Does downvoting that make me a sissy?

Comment: @Hiro Protagonist - Why remove the code snippet? Now "If I run the code below" doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really about JavaScript - it's more about the **browser** and the way it's handling JavaScript.

Each browser is doing this differently, but most modern browsers won't let JavaScript take 100% of the resources to prevent the client machine from crashing.

Bottom line you can't do such thing with client side scripting, you'll have to use "real" application with full access to the computer.

Answer (score 4):

> Suppose doing and addition, reading a clock, and doing a compare takes
>   100x the simplest operation (very conservative), I get (.1MHz * 100) =
>   1MHz.

This is **not** how computers work and measuring speed like this is not going to get you anywhere. Besides, it depends a lot on the JavaScript engine being used. I heard a lot of good things about the V8 JS engine that Chrome uses, Opera's seems to be pretty fast too.

So try it with different browsers to get a real comparison. But if you want to measure how much time it took to do some operation (pseudo code):

```
var start = get_current_time(); 
// do the complex operation
var end = get_current_time ();

var time_it_took = end - start;
```

The time functions should have as small a granularity as possible.

Comment: The thing is, getting the current time is always going to involve making a system call of some sort.  In other words, it's a trip into the operating system, and that's always going to be expensive.

Answer (score 2):

Well for one thing you would be creating a new date object every time thorugh the loop -- why not create the date object for comparision before you enter the loop?

Comment: Because he needs to check the current time on each iteration; otherwise the loop won't know when to stop.

Comment: Sure -- call getTime each time through the loop -- but don't create a new object each time

Comment: That's not how JavaScript Date objects work, however. The `getTime()` routine returns the timestamp value for that particular object, not the current system time.  For a given Date object the value will never change (unless the object itself is explicitly changed).

Comment: Well one learns something new everyday -- there's no indication in the w3c docs that the time once returned is immutable -- (at least not one I could find) but maybe that's a sensible thing

Comment: On that note, according to Mozilla there's a `.now()` function on the Date constructor that returns the current system time!  Something I didn't know.  (Don't know whether it's available in browsers other than Firefox.)